# How to modify a link url before it is navigated to

Tags: python, hyperlink, pyqt5, qwebenginepage

I want to catch a click on a page and add at the anchor link some text.

For example, If the user click on an anchor with href `mysite.com/about`, I want modify the link in: `mysite.com/about?myvar=value`

I used QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor but the click on the link is not catched.

What I am doing wrong?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os
import sys

class MyPage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPage, self).__init__(parent)
    def triggerAction(self, action, checked=False):
        if action == QWebEnginePage.OpenLinkInNewWindow:
            self.createWindow(QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserWindow)

        return super(MyPage, self).triggerAction(action, checked)
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, navtype, mainframe):
        if navtype == QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
            # go somewhere else
            self.setUrl(QUrl('https://wikipedia.org'))
            # abort the current navigation
            return False
        return super(MyPage, self).acceptNavigationRequest(url, navtype, mainframe)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.myPage = MyPage(self) #fab
        #self.setPage(self.myPage) #fab

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(WEBSITE_HOME))

        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        navtb.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
#        self.addToolBar(navtb)

        back_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'arrow-back.png')), "Back", self)
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page")
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)

        next_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'arrow-forward.png')), "Forward", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page")
        next_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'refresh.png')), "Reload", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page")
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)

        home_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'home.png')), "Home", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home")
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        stop_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'cross-circle.png')), "Stop", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page")
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)

        navtb.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.PreventContextMenu)

        self.show()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'ma-icon-64.png')))

    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("%s - Title" % title)

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(WEBSITE_LOGIN))

    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            self.webView = MyWindow()
            self.webView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            self.webView.show()
            return self.webView
        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windowType)

WEBSITE_HOME = "http://google.com"
WEBSITE_LOGIN = "http://google.com"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You want to modify the HTML from the outside (`self.browser`)?

Comment: Yes, I would add some text on the url at the click

Comment: Do you control the HTML or does it come from a 3rd party server?

Comment: The html is from myweb site, so it's on my control

Comment: Then I suggest you implement this using JavaScript *inside* the HTML.

Comment: But I have to add a value that is stored in python app

Comment: @michele You need to use [QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html) to modify a url before the browser navigates to it.

Comment: @ekhumoro can you give me an example of this? thanks

Comment: @ekhumoro can you give me an example of this? I have writen some code but is not working. The click on the link is not intercepted. thanks

Comment: @michele 
I have corrected your code, now the interceptor works, but I could not discriminate the origin of the links

Comment: How can I modify the value of info.requestUrl() ? thanks @eyllanesc

Comment: @michele 
if you want to redirect to another url you should use: `info.redirect(QUrl("foo.com"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to modify/replace a url before a link is navigated to, perhaps the simplest solution is to reimplement [acceptNavigationRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest):

```
class MyPage(QWebEnginePage):    
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, navtype, mainframe):
        if navtype == QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
            # go somewhere else
            self.setUrl(QUrl('https://wikipedia.org'))
            # abort the current navigation
            return False
        return super(MyPage, self).acceptNavigationRequest(url, navtype, mainframe)
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working...what I am doing wrong? I have modified the code in top post

Comment: Ok now it works, I arrive to self.setUrl. But In this method, how can I read the URL? I have to add a GET parameter in the URL that have to be visited. something like self.setUrl(self.getUrl()+ "myVar=123")) @ekhumoro

Comment: @michele The `url` is passed as the first argument.